# How to output tests in Azure Devops for javascript tests?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, node-modules

When I run Pipeline, I see 3 tabs: Summary, Tests, Code coverage. But not all tests are displayed in the tests tab, unlike the Code coverage tab, where unit tests from two tests 'server :: tests' and 'client :: tests' are displayed. **How do I make 'Client :: tests' appear in the Tests tab in the pipeline startup, after it ends?** I use build.cake.
This it build.cake:

```
Task("003-Tests")
    .IsDependentOn("Server :: Tests")
    .IsDependentOn("Client :: Tests")
    ;

 Task("Server :: Tests")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        var coverSettings = new OpenCoverSettings()
            .WithFilter($"+[{SolutionName}.*]*")
            .WithFilter($"-[{SolutionName}.*.Tests*]*");
        coverSettings.SkipAutoProps = true;
        coverSettings.Register = "Path64";
        coverSettings.MergeByHash = true;
        coverSettings.NoDefaultFilters = true;
        coverSettings.ReturnTargetCodeOffset = 0;

        void applyExclude<T>(ISet<T> filtersSet, string paramValue, Func<string, T> mapper)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramValue))
            {
                var excludes = paramValue.Split(',').Select(mapper);
                filtersSet.UnionWith(excludes);
            }
        }

        applyExclude(coverSettings.ExcludedAttributeFilters, "*ExcludeFromCodeCoverage*", x => x);
        applyExclude(coverSettings.ExcludedFileFilters,      "*.Generated.cs;*\\App_Start\\*", x => x);

        var directories = GetDirectories(
                $"{SrcDir}/**/bin", 
                new GlobberSettings { Predicate = fileSystemInfo => !fileSystemInfo.Path.FullPath.EndsWith("node_modules", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) }
            );
        foreach (var directory in directories)
        {
            coverSettings.SearchDirectories.Add(directory);
        }

        var OutputDirectory = $"{ReportTargetDir}/tests/";
        var xUnitTestsCoverageOutputDir = $"{OutputDirectory}/xUnit";

        EnsureDirectoryExists(xUnitTestsCoverageOutputDir);

        var openCoverResultsFilePath = new FilePath($"{xUnitTestsCoverageOutputDir}/coverage.xml");

        var xUnit2Settings = new XUnit2Settings {
                XmlReport = true,
                Parallelism = ParallelismOption.None,
                NoAppDomain = false,
                OutputDirectory = OutputDirectory,
                ReportName = "xUnitTestResults",
                ShadowCopy = false
            };

        OpenCover(
            tool => { tool.XUnit2($"{SrcDir}/**/tests/bin/*.Tests.dll", xUnit2Settings); }, 
            openCoverResultsFilePath, 
            coverSettings
        );

        ReportGenerator(openCoverResultsFilePath, xUnitTestsCoverageOutputDir);

        var converterExecutablePath = Context.Tools.Resolve("OpenCoverToCoberturaConverter.exe");
        StartProcess(converterExecutablePath, new ProcessSettings {
            Arguments = new ProcessArgumentBuilder()
                .Append($"-input:\"{openCoverResultsFilePath}\"")
                .Append($"-output:\"{xUnitTestsCoverageOutputDir}/cobertura-coverage.xml\"")
        });
    })
    .OnError(exception =>
    {
        Error(exception);
    })
    ;

Task("Client :: Tests")
    .Does(() => 
    {
        var settings = new NpmRunScriptSettings();
    
        settings.ScriptName = $"check-tests";
        settings.LogLevel = NpmLogLevel.Error;
        settings.FromPath(ClientFolderPath);
        
        NpmRunScript(settings);
     })
     ;
```

And this is pipeline tasks. As you can see, build.cake runs the 'Client :: tests' described in the package.json file:

```
          - task: Cake@2
            displayName: Run Unit tests BE
            condition: Or(eq(variables['changesBE'], 'true'), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
            inputs:
              script: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/build.cake"
              target: "Server :: Tests"
              verbosity: "Quiet"
              Version: "1.3.0"
          
          - task: Cake@2
            displayName: Run Unit tests FE
            condition: Or(eq(variables['changesFE'], 'true'), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
            inputs:
              script: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/build.cake"
              target: "Client :: Tests"
              verbosity: "Quiet"
              Version: "1.3.0"                              
          
          - task: PublishTestResults@2
            displayName: Publish BE test results
            inputs:
              testResultsFormat: "XUnit"
              testResultsFiles: "**/*.xml"
              searchFolder: "$(ArtifactsLocation)/tests"
              mergeTestResults: true

          - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
            displayName: Publish FE code coverage
            inputs:
              codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
              summaryFileLocation: $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/**/cobertura-coverage.xml
              failIfCoverageEmpty: false
```

and package.json:

```
"check-tests": "craco test --maxWorkers=25% --watchAll=false --silent --coverage --coverageReporters=cobertura"
```

Look, only 2 tests in 'tests' tab:
[image]

Comment: You can download the test results from the pipeline and open them from your local machine to check if you can see all your tests.  If you can see all tests, please check if there is the same issue using [Visual Studio Test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops)? Also, you can change "searchFolder" of PublishTestResults task to "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)" to check if you can see all the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Jest and 'craco'. In craco.config.js I added:

```
testResultsProcessor: './node_modules/jest-junit-reporter'
```

Full Jest config:

```
jest: {
    configure: {
      preset: 'ts-jest',
      moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, {
        prefix: '<rootDir>/src/',
      }),
      modulePathIgnorePatterns: [
        '<rootDir>/src/hooks',
        '<rootDir>/src/redux',
        '<rootDir>/src/temp',
      ],
      collectCoverageFrom: [
        '!**/node_modules/**',
        '!src/**/*.stories.tsx',
        '!src/lib/*.(j|t)s',
        '!src/*.(j|t)sx',
      ],
      coverageThreshold: {
        global: {
          statements: 70,
          branches: 70,
          functions: 70,
          lines: 80,
        },
      },
      testResultsProcessor: './node_modules/jest-junit-reporter',
    },
```

After that test results in azure devops runs appear.

Comment: It's great to know you resolve the issue. In order to let others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly, it's suggested that you accept your answer according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks!